# Implement a real time best-fit memory allocation algorithm in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, operating-system

We have this algorithm called "best-fit" that the Operating System uses to assign memory to processes that needs it. So what I wanted to do is, make a C code that can find the holes in the system's memory and fit processes to it, in real time,like what any OS does. I am trying to implement this on a Linux system.I know that /dev/mem acts as a interface to the physical memory, so I was going to try to use the hexdump of /dev/mem to somehow get the holes in the system memory. But I do not know whether that is the best way of doing this. So, Can someone please help point me in the right direction on how to go about implementing something like this?

Comment: What research have you done so far? or to put it another way http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Well I know that /dev/mem is the interface to read/write to the physical memory. Was thinking of processing the hexdump of /dev/mem to give me the holes in the system.. But I don't know if that is the best way of going about this.

Comment: ok, basically you need to think about what you want to ask and how to ask it, at the moment this question will most likely be ignored or downvoted - explain more but narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: Thanks! I modified the question now, by adding the research I did to the question, to help users get a better idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think you need a better understanding of physcial memory vs. virtual addressing.

Comment: This is for a class right? Do you need to model a best-fit algorithm and show it simulating how it works in reality? If so I think you shouldn't be looking at /Dev/Mem - you just simulate what would happen if processes use the memory...

Comment: The original code was just supposed to have an user input the number of holes and processes , along with the size of the holes and processes, and then run the best fit on it. I just wanted to implement the same thing , but by computing the actual free memory in the system and then using best fit, just to see how operating  systems actually work..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you can use Priority Search Trees for implementing a simple Best Fit or First Fit algorithm. You can read about Priority Search Trees here: http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~sahni/cop5536/presentations.htm (Lecture 35's presentation)

The algorithm implementation is explained in the next lecture (36's presentation).